# Set TomEE conf/system.properties properties from command line using TomEE Maven Plugin

Tags: maven, apache-tomee, tomee-8

I'd like to set up a one-liner to deploy my webapp in TomEE using Maven TomEE plugin. Normally, I'd just put the .war artifact in `<tomee-home>/webapps/` and set up `<tomee-home>/conf/system.properties` in a way like this:

```
myAppDS.jdbcUrl = jdbc:mysql://<host>:<port>/<schemaName>
myAppDS.password = <db user password>
myAppDS.userName = <db user name>
```

But how can I set these properties in command line using `maven tomee:run`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer the `tomee.xml` configuration to declare resources while using the TomEE Maven Plugin.

You can define your datasource in the TomEE Maven Plugin (similar to `conf/tomee.xml` in a standalone deployment) as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tomee>
    <Resource id="myDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        JtaManaged = true
        driverClassName = ${jdbc.driver}
        url = ${jdbc.url}
        username = ${jdbc.user}
        password = ${jdbc.pw}
    </Resource>
</tomee>
```

and reference the folder containing the `tomee.xml` via `<config>` in the TomEE Maven Plugin `<configuration>` section.

Alternative would be to use a `resources.xml` in `WEB-INF` of your web application:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <Resource id="myDS" type="javax.sql.DataSource">
        JtaManaged = true
      
        driverClassName = ${jdbc.driver}
        url = ${jdbc.url}
        username = ${jdbc.user}
        password = ${jdbc.pw}
    </Resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have already defined WEB-INF/resources.xml, but I'd like to set some parameters in the command line. Could i instead use the ${...} notation in resources.xml and substitute with CLI parameters?

Comment: If you are building the project beforehand you could use Maven resource filtering to adjust the values as desired